# convert mount command to fstab

Tags: 16.04, fstab

How could I convert these commands into fstab?

```
/bin/mount --make-rshared /
/bin/mount --bind /with /with
/bin/mount --make-rprivate /with
/bin/mount -t tmpfs company-with-global /with
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage for `mount` says in the chapter about the `shared subtree operations`:

```
Since  util-linux 2.23 the mount command allows to use several propagation flags together and also together with other mount operations.  This feature is EXPERIMENTAL.  The propaga‐
tion flags are applied by additional mount(2) syscalls when the preceding mount operations were successful.  Note that this use case is not atomic.  It is possible  to  specify  the
propagation flags in fstab(5) as mount options (private, slave, shared, unbindable, rprivate, rslave, rshared, runbindable).
```

This means:

- add option `rshared` to the options for mounting `/`
- add a new `bind` mount entry for `/with` with the `rprivate` option
- add a new mount entry for the `tmpfs` mount

(I think your `/bin/mount --bind /with /with`is a typo?)

Never tried that, but maybe it works.